# Sticky 'back to top' button works in iMac Firefox but not in Safari, Chrome or on Android phone

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome, safari

I read with interest Will Ryan's question of 12 March 2014 at 19:28, as I was having problems with the same "sticky 'back to top' button" tutorial. My button didn't even appear. But I rewrote my code according to the discussion suggestions and got it to work perfectly -- in Firefox, on my iMac. But it won't work in either Safari or Chrome on my iMac, or on my Samsung Galaxy 4GLTE. I checked for errors in the developer tools for Safari and Chrome but they showed none. I thought it might be a Z-index layer problem but my efforts there failed.
Here is the site: http://willsoper.net/
Thanks.

Comment: Weird as my chrome developer tools drop me an error:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function script.js:17
Also your container floats are not cleared correctly in your last section #text_column.

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to LJ_1102. I saw this error message, too, but chose to ignore it after seeing it while researching an earlier problem and reading this by @Oladipo Olasemo , from 28 Jul at 12:46:

> Usually when you get this problem, it happens cause a script is trying
>   to reference an element that doesn't exist yet while the page is
>   loading.
>
> As richie mentioned: The HTML parser will parse the HTML content from
>   top to bottom….
>
> So you can add your javascript references to the bottom of the html
>   file, this will not only improve performance, it will also ensure that
>   all elements referenced in your script files have already been loaded
>   by the HTML Parser.

When I read that, I moved my `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` just to the bottom of my list of such scripts in the head and this immediately and totally solved that first problem, in which, like this one, the code worked in FF but failed in Chrome and Safari.

Now, when I read LJ's comment above, it inspired me to reread Oladipo's comment and move my `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` out of the head and all the way to the bottom of my body code. This immediately and totally solved the problem and my "back to top" button now works in not only FF, but also Chrome, Safari and on my Android smartphone. (And the first problem also remains resolved.)

I will now research LJ's comment about my container floats, which I knew were wrong but didn't know how to fix.